Calculating the uncertainty of a very complicated variable
You have taken $N \gg 1$ measurements of a group of variables $V$. You want to estimate the value of a quantity $\mu$ that can be estimated from these variables. Fortunately you have a formula $\mu(V)$ available to do this, so it is just a matter of calculating this quantity.
However, you also need to estimate the uncertainty on $\mu(V)$. How do you estimate the uncertainty?
Clarifying example: $V$ could be given by two variables $x, y$ of mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$ and $\mu$ could be the linear regression coefficient between the two. In this case it is easy to estimate it as the mean of $x_i y_i$ divided by the mean of $x_i^2$, and this gives the function $\mu$. I think it is a bit more difficult but still doable to derive a formula for the uncertainty on $\mu$. But how to estimate the uncertainty if the function $\mu$ is very complicated or even known only to the computer, for example, if $\mu$ comes from a numerical account?
Note: I think there will not be a solution that works for every possible scenario but IMO there are reasonable methods that usually work. I am not asking necessarily for mathematical demonstrations, but for common sense solution (if anyone wants to take turns in mathematical demonstrations, they are free to do so!)

How is "uncertainty" defined?

Just bootstrap the distribution of mu(V) by repeatedly sampling complete observations V (complete rows). Then compute the standard deviation of this distribution. This is better than linear "propagation of error"

@Ggjj11 Could you expand on this comment in an answer?

This post has some more details: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233804/bootstrap-vs-monte-carlo-error-estimation
