Using T-Distribution for Parametric Bootstrap Confidence Intervals: Which Sample Size to Use?
I have a question regarding the calculation of bootstrap confidence intervals. My original sample size is relatively small, but after applying bootstrap resampling within groups, I obtained a bell-shaped distribution. Based on this, I believe it's reasonable to use a parametric method for confidence interval calculation.
I've decided to use the T-distribution method with the formula:
$$CI = \bar{X} \pm t_{\alpha/2, \, n-1} \times \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$$
My question is: when calculating the confidence interval, what value should I use for

n? Should it be the size of my original sample, or the number of bootstrap iterations (e.g., if I used 1000 iterations, should =1000)?
Thanks in advance for your insights!

Consider this: what does the number of bootstrap iterations tell you about the data?  Consider, too, that someone with enough computing resources could make $n$ so large that the CI shrinks down to $\bar X$ itself.  What information does that give you about your statistical question?

Here’s a rephrased version of your response:
I originally thought that increasing the number of bootstrap iterations would narrow the confidence interval down to the sample mean itself, implying that the data might not exhibit enough variability to justify a wide confidence interval. Is this interpretation incorrect?

No.  It sounds like you would benefit from a good description of what bootstrapping is.  Some can be found here on CV, such as at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26502.  The point is that because $n$ (the number of bootstrap iterations) is irrelevant--it contains no information whatsoever about the data--then any procedure that depends on $n$ is arbitrary.

Increasing the number of bootstrap iterations improves the accuracy of the sampling distribution approximation but doesn’t change the data’s inherent variability.
The confidence interval reflects variability in the original sample, not the number of iterations. The iterations stabilize the estimate but don't shrink the interval.
Since my goal is to assess the data’s variability, I should base the calculation on the original sample size. Even with many iterations, the confidence interval won’t be affected as its width depends on the variability in the original sample. Correct?

That sounds much better!

Increasing the number of bootstrap iterations improves the accuracy of the sampling distribution approximation but doesn’t change the data’s inherent variability.
The confidence interval reflects variability in the original sample, not the number of iterations. The iterations stabilize the estimate but don't shrink the interval. Since I aim to assess the data’s variability, I have decided to base the calculation on the original sample size.
